# "at next level" in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

What does the 'at next level' bit mean in the following notation (given that the level is already specified):

```
Reserved Notation "t1 ->> t2" (left associativity, at level 69, t2 at next level). 
...
where "t1 ->> t2" := (xform t1 t2).
```

where xform is a function defined in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `a ->> b ->> c`. There are two ways to parse it, either `t1` is `a` and `t2` is `b ->> c`, or `t1` is `a ->> b` and `t2` is `c`. Because `t2` is marked `at next level`, only a notation with a level lower than `69` can be used in there, which makes `b ->> c` impossible (unless parenthesized). So, `a ->> b ->> c` is parsed as `(a ->> b) ->> c`.

Note that `t2 at next level` is redundant in the above notation. Indeed, attribute `left associative` already forces `at next level` on the term at the right end. (While `right associativity` forces `at next level` on the term at the left end.)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't understand what 'at next level' means? Does it mean that notations inside t2 will get level 69 + 1 = 70? (But what if such a notation was already predefined a level when it was defined, then will it be 70 or would it be it's level when the notation was defined?

Comment: Consider `a ->> b ->> c`. There are two ways to parse it, either `t1` is `a` and `t2` is `b ->> c`, or `t1` is `a ->> b` and `t2` is `c`. Because `t2` is `at next level`, the level 69 of `b ->> c` makes it incompatible with it. So, `a ->> b ->> c` is parsed as `(a ->> b) ->> c`.

Comment: `at next level` means "at next *lower* level", since lower levels bind tighter than higher layers. `t2` is parsed at level 68. This prevents `->>` from appearing at top level in `t2`, since it requires level 69. So `a ->> b ->> c` can't be `a ->> (b ->> c)`, since `b ->> c` is at level 69 but `a ->> _` needs it to be at level 68. Instead it is parsed as `(a ->> b) ->> c`.

Comment: Could you please consider adding it to your answer, as—in my opinion—your comment is actually the answer to the original question.